# Preencher uma tabela ao selecionar um p:tab

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-3.5

Tenho duas tabelas em Tabs diferentes e ao clicar em cada uma delas, a tabela deve ser preenchida. Eu tô usando a mesma lista para preencher as duas tabelas, o que muda é o SQL pra consulta que varia de acordo com a aba clicada. Mas as tabelas não estão sendo preenchidas de forma nenhuma, as duas tabelas aparecem vazias.

**TabView**

```
<p:tabView>
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.onTabChange}" update="@([id$=blocoListagemArts])"/>

                <p:tab title="ARTs que não possuem Livro de Ordem">
                    <p:outputPanel id="blocoListagemArtsComLivro">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.artsAptas}" 
                                 id="tableArtsSemLivroOrdem" 
                                 rowKey="#{item.numeroArt}" var="item"
                                 emptyMessage="Você não possui ARTs sem Livro de Ordem"
                                 paginator="true" rows="20">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            ARTs de Obras/Serviços sem Livro de Ordem
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Numero da ART" sortBy="#{item.numeroArt}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.numeroArt}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Tipo de ART" sortBy="#{item.tipoArt.descricao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.tipoArt.descricao}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Data de Elaboração" sortBy="#{item.dataElaboracao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.dataElaboracao}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Proprietário" sortBy="#{item.nomeProprietario}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.nomeProprietario}" />
                        </p:column>

                     <p:column headerText="Livro de Ordem">
                            <p:commandLink id="criarLivroOrdemButton"
                                       immediate="true"
                                       rendered="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.renderizarBotaoCriarLivro(item.numeroArt)}"
                                       onclick="dialogLivroOrdem.show();"
                                       update="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.componentes}">

                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.artApta}"/>

                                <p:graphicImage alt="Criar/Ver" value="../imagens/site/adicionar.png" />

                            </p:commandLink>

                            <p:commandLink immediate="true"
                                       update="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.componentes}"
                                       rendered="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.renderizarBotaoVerLivro(item.numeroArt)}"
                                       onclick="javascript:window.location='livroOrdem.jsf?a=#{item.numeroArt}'; return false;">

                                <p:graphicImage alt="Ver Livro de Ordem" value="../imagens/site/detail.png" />

                            </p:commandLink>

                      </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab title="ARTs que possuem Livro de Ordem">
                    <p:outputPanel id="blocoListagemArtsSemLivro">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.artsAptas}" 
                         id="tableArtsComLivroOrdem" 
                         rowKey="#{item.numeroArt}" var="item"
                         emptyMessage="Você não possui ARTs com Livro de Ordem"
                         paginator="true" rows="20">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            ARTs de Obras/Serviços com Livro de Ordem
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Numero da ART" sortBy="#{item.numeroArt}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.numeroArt}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Tipo de ART" sortBy="#{item.tipoArt.descricao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.tipoArt.descricao}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Data de Elaboração" sortBy="#{item.dataElaboracao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.dataElaboracao}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Proprietário" sortBy="#{item.nomeProprietario}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.nomeProprietario}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Livro de Ordem">
                               <p:commandLink id="criarLivroOrdemButton"
                                           immediate="true"
                                           rendered="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.renderizarBotaoCriarLivro(item.numeroArt)}"
                                           onclick="dialogLivroOrdem.show();"
                                           update="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.componentes}">

                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.artApta}"/>

                                    <p:graphicImage alt="Criar/Ver" value="../imagens/site/adicionar.png" />

                               </p:commandLink>

                               <p:commandLink immediate="true"
                                           update="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.componentes}"
                                           rendered="#{artsAptasLivroOrdemController.renderizarBotaoVerLivro(item.numeroArt)}"
                                           onclick="javascript:window.location='livroOrdem.jsf?a=#{item.numeroArt}'; return false;">

                                    <p:graphicImage alt="Ver Livro de Ordem" value="../imagens/site/detail.png" />

                               </p:commandLink>

                         </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                   </p:outputPanel>
                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>
```

**onTabChange**

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELResolver resolver = context.getApplication().getELResolver();
    LoginControllerOnline controller = new LoginControllerOnline();
    controller = (LoginControllerOnline) resolver.getValue(context.getELContext(), null, "loginControllerOnline");
    pessoa = controller.getPessoa();
    String query = "";
    artsAptas.clear();

    if(pessoa instanceof Profissional) {
        Profissional profissional = (Profissional) pessoa;

        if(event.getTab().getTitle().equals("ARTs que não possuem Livro de Ordem")) {
            query = "SELECT a.numeroart, a.dataElaboracao, a.nomeProprietario, a.cepobraservico, a.tipologradouroobraservico, "
                + "a.logradouroobraservico, a.numeroobraservico, a.bairroobraservico, a.cidadeobraservico, a.ufobraservico, a.datainicioobraservico, "
                + "t.idTipoArt, t.descricao AS tipoArt, sa.descricao AS descricao  "
                + "FROM Art a "
                + "LEFT JOIN pessoa p ON p.codigo = a.codigoprofissionalcontratado "
                + "LEFT JOIN TipoArt t ON t.idTipoArt = a.tipoArt_idTipoArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN HistoricoSituacaoArt hsa ON hsa.art_numeroart = a.numeroArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN SituacaoArt sa ON sa.idSituacaoArt = hsa.idSituacaoArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN LivroOrdem lo ON lo.art_numeroArt = a.numeroArt "
                + "WHERE (a.codigoprofissionalcontratado = :codigo) AND (t.descricao = 'ART de Obra ou Serviço') "
                + "AND (hsa.dataEfetivacao IN (SELECT MAX(dataEfetivacao) FROM HistoricoSituacaoArt hsa WHERE hsa.art_numeroArt = a.numeroArt)) "
                + "AND (lo.art_numeroArt IS NOT NULL) ";

            if(!nomeProprietarioPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
                query += "AND (LOWER(a.nomeProprietario) LIKE LOWER(:nomeProprietarioPesquisa))";
                params.put("nomeProprietarioPesquisa", nomeProprietarioPesquisa);
            }

            else if(!numeroArtPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
               query += "AND (a.numeroArt = :numeroArtPesquisa)";
               params.put("numeroArtPesquisa", numeroArtPesquisa);
            }

            else if(!numeroArtPesquisa.isEmpty() && !nomeProprietarioPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
                query += "AND (a.numeroArt = :numeroArtPesquisa) AND (a.nomeProprietario = :nomeProprietarioPesquisa)";
                params.put("numeroArtPesquisa", numeroArtPesquisa);
                params.put("nomeProprietarioPesquisa", nomeProprietarioPesquisa);
            }

            params.put("codigo", profissional.getCodigo());
            System.out.println(event.getTab().getTitle());
        }

        else if(event.getTab().getTitle().equals("ARTs que possuem Livro de Ordem")) {
            query = "SELECT a.numeroart, a.dataElaboracao, a.nomeProprietario, a.cepobraservico, a.tipologradouroobraservico, "
                + "a.logradouroobraservico, a.numeroobraservico, a.bairroobraservico, a.cidadeobraservico, a.ufobraservico, a.datainicioobraservico, "
                + "t.idTipoArt, t.descricao AS tipoArt, sa.descricao AS descricao "
                + "FROM Art a "
                + "LEFT JOIN pessoa p ON p.codigo = a.codigoprofissionalcontratado "
                + "LEFT JOIN TipoArt t ON t.idTipoArt = a.tipoArt_idTipoArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN HistoricoSituacaoArt hsa ON hsa.art_numeroart = a.numeroArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN SituacaoArt sa ON sa.idSituacaoArt = hsa.idSituacaoArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN LivroOrdem lo ON lo.art_numeroArt = a.numeroArt "
                + "WHERE (a.codigoprofissionalcontratado = :codigo) AND (t.descricao = 'ART de Obra ou Serviço') "
                + "AND (hsa.dataEfetivacao IN (SELECT MAX(dataEfetivacao) FROM HistoricoSituacaoArt hsa WHERE hsa.art_numeroArt = a.numeroArt)) "
                + "AND (sa.descricao = 'Registrada') AND (lo.art_numeroArt IS NULL) ";

            if(!nomeProprietarioPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
                query += "AND (LOWER(a.nomeProprietario) LIKE LOWER(:nomeProprietarioPesquisa))";
                params.put("nomeProprietarioPesquisa", nomeProprietarioPesquisa);
            }

            else if(!numeroArtPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
               query += "AND (a.numeroArt = :numeroArtPesquisa)";
               params.put("numeroArtPesquisa", numeroArtPesquisa);
            }

            else if(!numeroArtPesquisa.isEmpty() && !nomeProprietarioPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
                query += "AND (a.numeroArt = :numeroArtPesquisa) AND (a.nomeProprietario = :nomeProprietarioPesquisa)";
                params.put("numeroArtPesquisa", numeroArtPesquisa);
                params.put("nomeProprietarioPesquisa", nomeProprietarioPesquisa);
            }

            params.put("codigo", profissional.getCodigo());
            System.out.println(event.getTab().getTitle());
        }
    }

    List<Object[]> arts = objectDao.listPesqQuery(query, params);

        for (Object[] o : arts) {
            Art artTemp = new Art();
            artTemp.setNumeroArt((String) o[0]);
            artTemp.setDataElaboracao((Date) o[1]);
            artTemp.setNomeProprietario((String) o[2]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setCep((String) o[3]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setTipoLogradouro((String) o[4]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setLogradouro((String) o[5]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setNumero((String) o[6]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setBairro((String) o[7]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setCidade((String) o[8]);
            artTemp.getEnderecoObraServico().setUf((String) o[9]);
            artTemp.setDataInicioObraServico((Date) o[10]);

            artTemp.setTipoArt(new TipoArt());
            BigInteger idTipoArt = (BigInteger) o[11];

            if (idTipoArt != null) {
                artTemp.getTipoArt().setIdTipoArt(idTipoArt.longValue());
            }

            artTemp.getTipoArt().setDescricao((String) o[12]);

            artsAptas.add(artTemp);
        }
}
```